# Java format indentation I/O

Tags: java, io, format

Im trying to indent my output 2 spaces to the right, is it possible to do it with .format instead of doing 2 space?

```
System.out.format("  %-15s %7.2f %5.0f %-20s\n", getName(), payPerHour, hours, task.getTask());
                   ^ //2 spaces in front
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, it is

```
System.out.format("%2s%-15s %7.2f %5.0f %-20s\n", " ", getName(), payPerHour, hours, task.getTask());
```